# wget alters file name after download

Tags: wget

I have written a script which downloads file from web server created by python simple http server. When I wget file at client machine, filename appends with ?. e.g. xyz.ipk downloaded as xyz.ipk? I have checked the script on my test environment everything is working fine.
     My client is Openwrt os and server is Ubuntu.

Comment: What is the exact `wget`syntax you are using? Have you tried with `-O file` parameter? (check wget man)

Comment: My crystal ball says: your input file has DOS line endings cr/lf, leading to a spurious cr at the end of your filenames.

Answer (score 1):

By default, wget bases the file name on the URL, not on what the server says the file name should be. To allow the server to choose the file name, use the option 
[`--content-disposition`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-Content_002dDisposition).